# Outlook Web App no longer working after web server rebuilt

Tags: exchange, website, outlook-web-app

Recently a server of ours went down and was rebuilt. The server hosted a website, and had links to various resources as well. At the moment, everything seems to be up and the website is accessible, except for one link: on the page is a link that when clicked is supposed to send you to the outlook web app login page. (Exchange is installed onto another server.) Before the server went down the page would load and people could get to their e-mail via the internet. Now, when you click on the page it results in a "server not found: can't find the server at [the website you're on]." However, the outlook office program and email connections on mobile devices like phones and ipads are still working correctly, pointed at that address, "mail.[address]." that address is just not accessible via the internet, and I don't know why.

Any thoughts?

Details: Exchange Server 2010

[Update] When we put in the ip for the server instead of the address name it works.

Comment: Adding a forward lookup zone to DNS seems to have got it working, but only locally - other computers aren't seeing any change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've written, it could be that the server has a new ip address and perhaps your DNS has a record for the old OWA host name pointing to an incorrect old static address.

You may also want to check the bindings for the OWA site in IIS to make sure that traffic is being routed correctly, although given you can browse it with an ip address this is unlikely to be the culprit.

Comment: Turns out yes, it was a DNS issue, I had apparently overlooked something. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Compare the link (on the webpage) with the actual public URL of your OWA server. If you don't know how to find that, it's in the Exchange Management Console, Exchange Management Shell, or Exchange Control Panel (depending on your version of Exchange, which you didn't tell us.)

You must have the wrong link on the webserver, since the OWA server (presumably a different webserver) is still up and running.

Comment: oh whoops, its exchange server 2010

Comment: Good lord - post the address as written in the page source, and what it is when you ask Exchange what it's external URL is.